Magento cloud docker PHP 8.3: unable to create new composer project
we've been using Magento docker images for dev and production sites for a couple years now and it works great. However for this latest version PHP 8.3 image, when trying to install magento via composer we keep getting the following error:
root@9e249fa63ca8:/app# composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.7 .
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition:2.4.7" project at "./"

In Process.php line 355:
                                   
  Unable to launch a new process.  
                                   

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]

This is the docker image we're using:
https://hub.docker.com/layers/magento/magento-cloud-docker-php/8.3-cli-1.3.7/images/sha256-3bec60cfe9302c3ccd9f726fb1c95ea393680b8f9eed75d3132d57c1aa3680a2?context=explore
I've always been using that Magento PHP docker base image but the latest version can't be used to create new composer project. Usually it works flawlessly on the older version, but for this PHP 8.3 it doesn't work as expected. Details explained above. Any help is very much appreciated.

We found the solution is to update docker engine to the latest version. We are using ubuntu 20.04 and we were using docker version 19 and 20. Yesterday we updated docker to the latest version 26 and now it works well.
